# Append component to element div or any existing in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

How to append a span (any element) to a div(or any element) in React ??
(Add the element inside without overriding)

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// For example we have a component which renders a <span>
//-----------------------------------------------------------
class MySpan extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span>My Added span</span>
    );
  }
}
```

```
//------------------------
//In jQuery we can do this to append an element
//------------------------

let html = '<span>My Added span</span>';
$('#myDiv').append(html);
```

**What is the equivalent in ReactJS ??**

Comment: You would simply include the component in the parent. `<div id="myDiv><MySpan /></div>`, or conditionally `<div id="myDiv">{condition && <MySpan />}</div>`

Comment: The parent <div id="myDiv></div> is displayed/rendered by php/html not in javasvript

Comment: Since React is still JavaScript, you could still use simple JS to do this operation. It is nasty, but works: document.getElementById("mySpan").appendChild(myHtml). Else, you should think about conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the div element by id and mount the span component.

```js
class MySpan extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span>My Added span</span>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MySpan/>, document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Make sure you include the react-dom script in your php template